# Text based game "Hunt the Wumpus"

Tags: c++, game

This code was reworked and posted here:[Text based game “Hunt the Wumpus” Version 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/199931/text-based-game-hunt-the-wumpus-version-2)

The following game was a excercise in the PPP book by Stroustrup:

> Implement a version of the game "Hunt the Wumpus". 
>   Hunt the Wumpus" (or just "Wump") is a simple (non-graphically) computer game originally invented by Gregory Yob.
>   The basic premise is that a rather smelly monster lives in a dark cave consisting of connected rooms. Your job is to slay the wumpus using bow and arrow. In addition to the wumpus, the cave has two hazards: bottomless pits and giant bats. If you enter a room with a bat, the bat picks you up and drops you into another room. If you enter a room with a bottomless pit, its the end of the game for you. If you enter the room with the Wumpus he eats you. When you enter a room you will be told if a hazard is nearby:
>   "I smell the wumpus": It´s in an adjoining room.
>   "I feel a breeze": One of the adjoining rooms is a bottomless pit.
>   "I hear a bat": A giant bat is in an adjoining room.
>   
>   For your convenience, rooms are numbered. Every room is connected by tunnels to three other rooms. When entering a room, you are told something like " You are in room 12; there are tunnels to rooms 1,13, and 4: move or shoot?" Possible answers are m13 ("Move to room 13") and s13-4-3 ("Shoot an arrow through rooms 13,4, and 3"). The range of an arrow is three rooms. At the start of the game, you have five arrows.
>   The snag about shooting is that it wakes up the wumpus and he moves to a room adjoining the one he was in - that could be your room.
>   Be sure to have a way to produce a debug output of the state of the cave.

The excercises doesnt say how much bats or pits are in the game. I did some research and found that most implementations made like `count_of_rooms / 6` for the amount of bats and pits.

Here is my code:

**wumpus.h**

```
#ifndef WUMPUS_GUARD_110720182013
#define WUMPUS_GUARD_110720182013

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace wumpus {

    struct Room {
        Room(int rnum)
            :wumpus{ false }, pit{ false }, bat{ false }, player{ false }, rnumber{ rnum }
        {
            brooms.push_back(nullptr);
            brooms.push_back(nullptr);
            brooms.push_back(nullptr);
        }
        int rnumber;
        std::vector <Room*> brooms;         //pointer to 3 rooms next to this room
        bool wumpus;
        bool pit;
        bool bat;
        bool player;
    };

    class Dungeon {
    public:
        Dungeon();
        void indicate_hazards();
        bool shoot_arrow(std::vector<int> tar_rooms);
        bool Dungeon::move_wumpus();
        bool move_player(int tar);
        void debug();                   //shows the status of the cave for debug purpose
        std::vector<int> neigbour_rooms(int room);
        int current_room();
    private:
        static constexpr int count_of_arrows = 5;
        static constexpr int count_of_rooms = 12;
        static constexpr int count_of_pits = count_of_rooms / 6;
        static constexpr int count_of_bats = count_of_rooms / 6;
        std::vector <Room> rooms;
        int arrows;
        int wumpus_room;
        int player_room;

        bool connect_rooms();
        bool room_is_full_connected(const int con, const std::vector<int>& crooms);
    };

    int get_random(int min, int max);
    void hunt_the_wumpus();
    void instructions();
    int select_room_to_move(Dungeon& d1);
    std::vector<int> select_rooms_to_shoot();

}

#endif
```

**wumpus.cpp**

```
#include "wumpus.h"

namespace wumpus {

Dungeon::Dungeon()
{
    //retry make the connections if not sucessfull
    while (true) {
        rooms.clear();
        for (int i = 1;i <= count_of_rooms;++i)     //create rooms
            rooms.push_back(i);

        if (connect_rooms())        //connect them
            break;
    }

    //add the wumpus
    wumpus_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
    rooms[wumpus_room - 1].wumpus = true;

    //add pit
    for (int i = 0; i < count_of_pits; ++i) {
        int pit_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
        while (rooms[pit_room - 1].wumpus == true //no wumpus or pit already in room
            || rooms[pit_room - 1].pit == true)
            pit_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
        rooms[pit_room - 1].pit = true;
    }

    //add bat
    for (int i = 0; i < count_of_bats; ++i) {
        int bat_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
        while (rooms[bat_room - 1].wumpus == true //no wumpus or pit or bat already in room
            || rooms[bat_room - 1].pit == true
            || rooms[bat_room - 1].bat == true)
            bat_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
        rooms[bat_room - 1].bat = true;
    }

    //add player
    player_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
    while (rooms[player_room - 1].wumpus == true //no wumpus or pit or bat already in room
        || rooms[player_room - 1].pit == true
        || rooms[player_room - 1].bat == true)
        player_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
    rooms[player_room - 1].player = true;

    arrows = count_of_arrows;
}

void Dungeon::indicate_hazards()
{
    bool found_bat = false;
    bool found_pit = false;

    for (auto& x : rooms[player_room - 1].brooms) {
        if (x->wumpus == true) { 
            std::cout << "I smell the wumpus\n";
        }
        if (x->pit == true && found_pit == false) {
            found_pit = true;
            std::cout << "I feel a breeze\n";
        }
        if (x->bat == true && found_bat == false) {
            found_bat = true;
            std::cout << "I hear a bat\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "You are in room " << rooms[player_room - 1].rnumber << "\n";
    std::cout << "You have "<<arrows<< " arrow(s) left\n";
    std::cout << "Tunnels lead to rooms " << rooms[player_room - 1].brooms[0]->rnumber << ", ";
    std::cout << rooms[player_room - 1].brooms[1]->rnumber << " and ";
    std::cout << rooms[player_room - 1].brooms[2]->rnumber << "\n";
    std::cout << "what do you want to do? (M)ove or (S)hoot?\n";
}

bool Dungeon::shoot_arrow(std::vector<int> tar_rooms)
    //trys to shoot in the supplied tar rooms an arrow
    //if the wumpus is hit returns true to indicate victory
    //moves the wumpus on fail
{
    --arrows;
    int curr_room = player_room - 1;
    for (const auto& tr : tar_rooms){
        bool room_reached = false;
        for (const auto& x : rooms[curr_room].brooms) {     //check if neigbour room is one of the vectors
            if (x->rnumber == tr) {
                room_reached = true;
                curr_room = x->rnumber - 1;
                if (rooms[curr_room].wumpus) {      //wumpus hit
                    std::cout << "!!!!!!YOU WON!!!!!!: You killed the Wumpus in room " << rooms[curr_room].rnumber << "\n";
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!room_reached) {    //if not end 
            std::cout << "Room " << tr << " could not be reached from arrow\n";
            return false;
        }           
    }
    if (arrows == 0) {
        std::cout << "You lost: You ran out of arrows";
        return true;
    }
}

bool Dungeon::move_wumpus() 
    //moves the wumpus with a chance of 75% to a new room
    //if player room is entered true is returned for game over
{
    if (get_random(1, 4) == 4)  // no movement on 4
        return false;
    else {
        rooms[wumpus_room - 1].wumpus = false;
        wumpus_room = rooms[wumpus_room - 1].brooms[get_random(0, 2)]->rnumber;
        rooms[wumpus_room - 1].wumpus = true;
        if (rooms[wumpus_room - 1].player) {
            std::cout << "You lost: Wumpus enters youre room and eats you\n";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool Dungeon::move_player(int tar)
    //trys to move player to the selected room
    //if deadly hazard like pit or wumpus is found return game over = true;
    //if bat is found choose new random room free from hazards to put the player
{
    for (auto& x : rooms[player_room - 1].brooms) {
        if (x->rnumber == tar) {
            if (x->wumpus == true) {
                std::cout << "You lost: You got eaten by the Wumpus\n";
                return true;
            }
            else if (x->pit == true) {
                std::cout << "You lost: You fell in a bottomless pit\n";
                return true;
            }
            else if (x->bat) {
                std::cout << "Gigantic bat appeared!!!\n";
                std::cout << "You got dragged to a new room\n";
                int rnd_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
                //Only put player in empty room
                while (rooms[rnd_room - 1].wumpus == true || rooms[rnd_room - 1].pit == true
                    || rooms[rnd_room - 1].bat == true || rooms[rnd_room - 1].player == true)
                    rnd_room = get_random(1, count_of_rooms);
                rooms[player_room - 1].player = false;
                player_room = rnd_room;
                rooms[player_room - 1].player = true;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                rooms[player_room - 1].player = false;
                player_room = tar;
                rooms[player_room - 1].player = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cerr << "Dungeon::move_player: Unknown target room entered";
    return false;
}

void Dungeon::debug()
{
    for (const auto&x : rooms) {
        std::cout << "Room " << x.rnumber << " connects to: ";
        for (const auto&y : x.brooms) {
            if (y != nullptr) std::cout << y->rnumber << " ";
            else std::cout << "np" << " ";
        }
        std::cout << " ";
        if(x.wumpus) std::cout << "wumpus:" << x.wumpus << " ";
        if(x.pit) std::cout << "pit:" << x.pit << " ";
        if(x.bat) std::cout << "bat:" << x.bat << " ";
        if(x.player) std::cout << "player:" << x.player << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

std::vector<int> Dungeon::neigbour_rooms(int room)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    ret.push_back(rooms[room - 1].brooms[0]->rnumber);
    ret.push_back(rooms[room - 1].brooms[1]->rnumber);
    ret.push_back(rooms[room - 1].brooms[2]->rnumber);
    return ret;
}

int Dungeon::current_room()
{
    return player_room;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------
//Private functions
//-------------------------------------------------------------

bool Dungeon::room_is_full_connected(const int con, const std::vector<int>& crooms)
    //checks if the room has already 3 connections so it is on the black list
{
    for (const auto &x : crooms) // room is on the black list
        if (x == con)
            return true;
    return false;
}

bool Dungeon::connect_rooms()
    //connects the rooms with random algorithm
    //it can happen that the last 2 rooms connected are in the same room 
    //e.g Room 2  connected to 4 np np. the last to connections are in the same room
    //in this case it is returned false to re run the connection algorithm
    //other case to restart 2 rooms left with one unconnected node because they are already connected
    //with each other
{
    std::vector <int> conn_rooms;
    while (conn_rooms.size() < count_of_rooms) {

        int min_room = 1;
        int max_room = count_of_rooms;

        int source_rnd_room = get_random(min_room, max_room);
        while (room_is_full_connected(source_rnd_room, conn_rooms))                                         //check if rnd room is on black list
            source_rnd_room = get_random(min_room, max_room);

        int target_rnd_room = get_random(min_room, max_room);
        while (room_is_full_connected(target_rnd_room, conn_rooms) || source_rnd_room == target_rnd_room) { //check if rnd room is on black list
            target_rnd_room = get_random(min_room, max_room);

            if (conn_rooms.size() == count_of_rooms - 2                     //special case for last 2 numbers to prevent infinite loop
                && room_is_full_connected(target_rnd_room, conn_rooms)
                && room_is_full_connected(source_rnd_room, conn_rooms)
                && source_rnd_room != target_rnd_room) {
                conn_rooms.push_back(source_rnd_room);
                conn_rooms.push_back(target_rnd_room);
            }
            if (conn_rooms.size() == count_of_rooms - 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        bool conn_full = true;
        bool tar_already_conn = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rooms[source_rnd_room - 1].brooms.size(); ++i) {
            if (rooms[source_rnd_room - 1].brooms[i] == nullptr) {
                conn_full = false;
                rooms[source_rnd_room - 1].brooms[i] = &rooms[target_rnd_room - 1];
                if (i == rooms[source_rnd_room - 1].brooms.size() - 1)
                    conn_full = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (rooms[source_rnd_room - 1].brooms[i]->rnumber == target_rnd_room) { //skip if room already leads to source_rnd_room
                tar_already_conn = true;
                break;          
            }
        }

        if (tar_already_conn && conn_rooms.size() == count_of_rooms - 2)
            return false;

        if (tar_already_conn)
            continue;

        if (conn_full)
            conn_rooms.push_back(source_rnd_room);

        conn_full = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rooms[target_rnd_room - 1].brooms.size(); ++i) {
            if (rooms[target_rnd_room - 1].brooms[i] == nullptr) {
                conn_full = false;
                rooms[target_rnd_room - 1].brooms[i] = &rooms[source_rnd_room - 1];
                if (i == rooms[target_rnd_room - 1].brooms.size() - 1)
                    conn_full = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (conn_full)
            conn_rooms.push_back(target_rnd_room);

    }
    return true;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------
//Helper functions
//-------------------------------------------------------------

int get_random(int min, int max)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(mt);
}

void hunt_the_wumpus()
{
    instructions();
    while (true)
    {
        Dungeon d1;
        while (true) {
            d1.indicate_hazards();
            std::string in;
            std::cin >> in;
            if (std::cin.fail()) {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(999, '\n');
                continue;
            }
            bool game_over = false;
            if (in == "m" || in == "M" || in == "Move" || in == "move") {
                game_over = d1.move_player(select_room_to_move(d1));
            }
            else if (in == "s" || in == "S" || in == "Shoot" || in == "shoot") {
                game_over = d1.shoot_arrow(select_rooms_to_shoot());
                if (game_over == true) { break; }
                game_over = d1.move_wumpus();
            }
            if (game_over == true) {
                break;
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Press any key to start a new game or (q)uit to end game\n";
        std::string in;
        std::cin >> in;
        if (in == "q" || in == "Q" || in == "Quit" || in == "quit")
            break;
    }
}

void instructions()
{
    std::cout <<
        "Welcome to \"Hunt the Wumpus\"!\n"
        "The wumpus lives in a cave of rooms.Each room has 3 tunnels leading to\n"
        "other rooms. (Look at a dodecahedron to see how this works - if you don't know\n"
        "what a dodecahedron is, ask someone).\n"
        "\n"
        "Hazards\n"
        "Bottomless pits - two rooms have bottomless pits in them.If you go there, you\n"
        "fall into the pit(and lose!)\n"
        "Super bats - two other rooms have super bats.If you go there, a bat grabs you\n"
        "and takes you to some other room at random. (Which may be troublesome).\n"
        "\n"
        "Wumpus\n"
        "The wumpus is not bothered by hazards(he has sucker feet and is too big for a\n"
        "bat to lift).Usually he is asleep.Two things wake him up : you shooting an\n"
        "arrow or you entering his room.\n"
        "\n"
        "If the wumpus wakes he moves(p = .75) one room or stays still(p = .25).After\n"
        "that, if he is where you are, he eats you up and you lose!\n"
        "\n"
        "You\n"
        "Each turn you may move or shoot a crooked arrow.\n"
        "Moving: you can move one room(thru one tunnel).\n"
        "Arrows : you have 5 arrows.You lose when you run out.Each arrow can go from 1\n"
        "to 3 rooms.You aim by telling the computer the rooms you want the arrow to go\n"
        "to.If the arrow can\'t go that way (if no tunnel) it moves at random to the\n"
        "next room.If the arrow hits the wumpus, you win.If the arrow hits you, you\n"
        "lose.\n"
        "\n"
        "Warnings\n"
        "When you are one room away from a wumpus or hazard, the computer says :\n"
        "\n"
        "Wumpus: \"I smell the wumpus\"\n"
        "Bat : \"I hear a bat\"\n"
        "Pit : \"I feel a breeze\"\n"
        "\n\n"
        "Press any key to start\n";
    char c;
    std::cin.get(c);
}

int select_room_to_move(Dungeon& d1)
{
    int in;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "To where??\n";
        in = 0;
        std::cin >> in;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(999, '\n');
            continue;
        }

        std::vector<int> nr = d1.neigbour_rooms(d1.current_room());

        if (in == nr[0] || in == nr[1] || in == nr[2])
            return in;
    }
}


std::vector<int> select_rooms_to_shoot()
{
    for(;;){
        std::cout << "Enter rooms you want to shoot the arrow (e.g. 2-3-12, eg 4-5, eg 2)\n";

        std::string in;
        std::cin >> in;

        std::istringstream ist{ in };
        std::vector<int> tar_rooms;

        bool bad_input = false;
        while (!ist.eof()) {
            int in_int;
            char in_char;
            ist >> in_int;
            if (ist.fail()) {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(999, '\n');
                bad_input = true;
                break;
            }
            tar_rooms.push_back(in_int);

            if (ist.eof()) break;

            ist >> in_char;
            if (ist.fail()) {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(999, '\n');
                bad_input = true;
                break;
            }
            if (in_char != '-') { bad_input = true; break; }
            if (tar_rooms.size() > 3) { bad_input = true;break; }
            if (ist.eof()) { bad_input = true;break; };//to prevent 2-3-12-  last sign must be integer
        }
        if (bad_input) continue;
        if (tar_rooms.size() <= 3)
            return tar_rooms;
    }
}
```

}

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "wumpus.h"


int main()
try {
    wumpus::hunt_the_wumpus();
}
catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "unknown error\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I wonder what can be improved to clean up the code. Is it a good idea to split the code into smaller classes?

Please let me know if the code is readable or if it needs improvements.

I want the code as clean as possible beause in the next step i want to make it a GUI game (using FLTK).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is too big for me to do a *full* review, but here are some random observations:

First, the standard miscellany.

- Good on you for not `using namespace std;` anywhere!
- Consider using `#pragma once` instead of the `#ifndef`/`#define` dance you're currently doing. (It's not standard but it's a lot more foolproof. Numbers such as your `110720182013` may change — and noise up your git logs when they do — but `#pragma once` endures.)
- Ending every program with `std::cin.get();` is a MSVC-ism. Learn to run your programs in the Command Prompt (a.k.a. Terminal) and you won't need to mess around with `cin.get()` anymore.

---

Now the naming. *Most* of your identifiers are inappropriate for a real codebase. For example, you have a vector that in a real program would be called something like [`neighbors`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neighbor) or `outgoing_passages`; you call it [`brooms`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/broom).

Some of your identifiers are at least plausibly related by abbreviation to their actual meanings; for example `int tar`, which from context clearly means something like `int target`. But you should still write them out! Remember, we write our C++ code for *people*, not for machines. (Machines are totally happy reading machine code.) So `rnd_room` should be `random_room`; `rnumber` should be `room_number` (or just `room`?), `tar_rooms` should be `target_rooms` (or `path`?), and so on.

---

Consider introducing a type alias

```
using RoomNumber = int;
```

so that you don't have to use unexplained `int` for so many different purposes.

---

Your helpdoc could *maybe* productively be rewritten to use a `R"(raw string)"` literal, which first appeared in C++11. I intensely dislike raw strings because of the `R".*(regex).*"` issue, but I also dislike having to manually place `\n` and `\"` in page-long C strings, so... in this case I'd consider it.

Speaking of your helpdoc, it's a copy of [Gregory Yob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_Yob)'s original, which is cool and all, but that means it is not an accurate description of what your program *actually does!*

> The wumpus lives in a cave of rooms. Each room has 3 tunnels leading to other rooms. (Look at a dodecahedron to see how this works — if you don't know what a dodecahedron is, ask someone).

Your code doesn't actually do this! To see one way to implement "randomly numbered rooms on a dodecahedron," you could do [this](https://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/251/25143.html). (Step 1: hard-code a map of a dodecahedron. Step 2: assign the numbers 1 through 20 to the vertices, at random.)

---

```
int get_random(int min, int max)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(mt);
}
```

This is an antipattern. Better would be:

```
int get_random(int min, int max)
{
    static std::mt19937 mt = []() {
        std::random_device rd;
        return std::mt19937(rd());
    }();
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(min, max);
    return distribution(mt);
}
```

This way you only create the `random_device` once per *run of the program*, instead of once per *random number generated.* Your intuition here should be that creating a `random_device` is equivalent to `open("/dev/urandom")`; so you don't want to do it often if you don't need to.

---

```
neigbour_rooms
```

Spell-check! (Protip: If you use full English words, instead of `tar` and `rnd` and such, then you can pretty much *literally* run spell-check on your code.)

---

```
struct Room {
    Room(int rnum)
        :wumpus{ false }, pit{ false }, bat{ false }, player{ false }, rnumber{ rnum }
    {
        brooms.push_back(nullptr);
        brooms.push_back(nullptr);
        brooms.push_back(nullptr);
    }
    int rnumber;
    std::vector <Room*> brooms;         //pointer to 3 rooms next to this room
    bool wumpus;
    bool pit;
    bool bat;
    bool player;
};
```

Two things about this struct. First, every constructor you write (regardless of number of parameters) should be `explicit`, unless you *deliberately* want to enable implicit conversion for some reason. Second, C++11 and later support in-line initializers for member data, so you should actually write it like this:

```
struct Room {
    explicit Room(int r) : room_number(r), neighbors(3, nullptr) {}
    int room_number;
    std::vector<Room*> neighbors;
    bool has_wumpus = false;
    bool has_pit = false;
    bool has_bat = false;
    bool has_player = false;
};
```

Notice that with the vector renamed to `neighbors`, we no longer need the long comment explaining about "brooms"! This is what people mean by "self-documenting code."  I've renamed the other members accordingly. Notice that `some_room.pit` is relatively clear, but `some_room.has_pit` is *100% unambiguous.* Strive for 100%!

---

```
int Dungeon::current_room()
{
    return player_room;
}
```

This is an interesting bit of code, because here we have a one-line function that claims to return "dungeon current room" but actually returns "player room." One or the other of these names is lying to us!

I think what it's actually returning is the room the *player* is currently in. (Why the `Dungeon` should care what room the player is in, I'm not sure.) The method should probably be named `player_room`, at which point we realize that the member variable `player_room` might as well be `public`.

(Or, if we're going the full OOP getters-and-setters route here, the private member variable should be named with a sigil such as `player_room_` or `m_player_room`, and orthogonally, the member function `int player_room() const` should have that `const`.

---

There's more, but that's a good stopping point for now, anyway.

Comment: What's the raw string literal "regex" issue that you are referring to?

Comment: To a Python programmer, `R".*(regex).*"` looks like it should be equivalent to `".*(regex).*"`, but in fact it is equivalent to `"regex"`. I have seen this crop up in the wild (although only ever in unit tests), and I think it's a big enough pitfall that people should at least be *advised* never to use `R""` syntax. That way, if they decide to use it anyway, maybe they'll be cautious and not trust their instincts as much as they would by default.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.  It's definitely improved over the last version, but there's more you could do.

### Omit the class name from member function declarations

It was probably just a typo or cut-and-paste error, but within the `Dungeon` class in `wumpus.h` we have this:

```
bool Dungeon::move_wumpus();
```

As you know (because this is the only place it's done otherwise) the extra qualification is not necessary here.  Instead, that should be:

```
bool move_wumpus();
```

### Always `return` an appropriate value

Your `shoot_array()` routine has control paths that cause it to end without `return`ing any `bool` value.  This is an error and should be fixed, probably most easily by simply adding `return false;` to the end.

### Prefer `std::array` to `std::vector` when fixed size is known at compile time

The way this game is constructed, there will always be 20 room, each with 3 neighbors.  For that reason, the `get_neighbor_room` should probably return a `std::array<Room_number, 3>` instead of a `std::vector<int>`.

### Don't create the random device every time

The `get_random` code is currently this:

```
int get_random(int min, int max)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(mt);
}
```

But we don't really need a new `rd` or a new `mt` each time.  I'd make both of these static.

### Don't hide loop exit conditions

In the `hunt_the_wumpus` routine, there are two nested loops both of which are `while (true)` but neither really continues forever.  Rather than hide the exit condition, state it up front to make it easier to read and understand.  For instance, the inner loop could be this:

```
for (bool gamme_over = false;  ) {
```

Then this rather perplexing bit of code at the end of the loop:

```
    else if (in == "s" || in == "S" || in == "Shoot" || in == "shoot") {
        game_over = d1.shoot_arrow(select_rooms_to_shoot());
        if (game_over == true) { break; }
        game_over = d1.move_wumpus();
    }
    if (game_over == true) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Becomes this:

```
    else if (in == "s" || in == "S" || in == "Shoot" || in == "shoot") {
        game_over = d1.shoot_arrow(select_rooms_to_shoot());
        if (!game_over) { 
            game_over = d1.move_wumpus();
        }
    }
}
```

Avoid a bunch of confusing `break` and `continue` statements and simplify and shorten the code at the same time.

### Simplify the room connection code

The `connect_rooms()` code is quite long and complex.  It can be much simplified by using a better algorithm.  Select two rooms at a time, connect them to each other (if they're not already connected) and move those to another vector.  Continue until the first vector is empty.  Then do that three more times.

### Make your classes work harder

The `room_is_full_connected` should be a member function of `Room`.  Here are functions I'd add to `Room`:

```
// return true if the passed room is already connected to this one
bool isConnected(const Room& other) const;
// return the number of connections from this room
bool connectionCount() const;
// return true if the passed room is this one or is connected
bool isSelfOrConnected(const Room& other) const;
// connect this room to the other
bool connect(Room& other);
// hazard checks
bool nearWumpus() const;
bool nearBat() const;
bool nearPit() const;
```

### Look out for member functions

There is a function in the current code with this prototype:

```
int select_room_to_move(Dungeon& d1);
```

Since it's being passed a non-const reference to a `Dungeon` anyway, it seems likely that this should instead be a member function.

### Simplify user input

The `select_rooms_to_shoot` is much longer and much more convoluted than necessary.  Consider a cleaner approach:

```
std::vector<int> select_rooms_to_shoot()
{
    std::vector<int> tar_rooms;
    for(bool bad_input{true}; bad_input;  ) {
        std::cout << "Enter rooms you want to shoot the arrow (e.g. 2-3-12, eg 4-5, eg 2)\n";

        std::string in;
        if (std::getline(std::cin, in)) {
            // replace non-digits with spaces
            std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), in.begin(), 
            [](char ch){
                return std::isdigit(ch) ? ch : ' ';
            });
            std::istringstream ist{ in };
            int roomnum;
            while (ist >> roomnum) {
                tar_rooms.push_back(roomnum);
            }
            bad_input = tar_rooms.empty() || tar_rooms.size() > 3;
        }
    }
    return tar_rooms;
}
```